# Finding if integral is convergent or not - struggling to find good integrals to compare to

Tags: calculus

**The problem**

Does $$\int_{10}^{\infty}\frac{x+ ln x}{x^2} \ dx$$

converge or not?

**My attempt**

I went ahead and tried to find functions which are strictly larger or smaller than the integrand to see if these converge/diverge but I can only find smaller functions that converge and larger functions that diverge, which tells me nothing about this integral.

The ones I tried are:

$$ \frac{1}{x^2} <  \frac{x+ ln x}{x^2} < \frac{x+ x}{x^2} = \frac{2}{x}$$

where the leftmost one converges and the rightmost one diverges

**What I need help with**

How am I supposed to find good functions to compare to? I don't only have an issue with this specific problem, but with every one of this type. I just happen to find the right function sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\ln(x)\ge0\forall x\ge1$,

$$\frac{x+\ln(x)}{x^2}\ge\frac{x+0}{x^2}=\frac1x$$

Thus, we know it diverges by the p-series.

Comment: Well, that was easy :)
Would you like to just write the conclusion that 1/x diverges so I can accept this as an answer?

Comment: @ejbs No problem :-) Sure hard to find simple things when you see a lot of logarithms and stuff.  Took me five minutes to realize $\ln(x)>0$  XD Oh dear...